# Determining prime numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that determines whether a value is a prime number and then displays a message to provide the outcome. Unfortunately, it doesn't work - no error messages displayed, and I can't see a logical reason why. ( For info, it calls a function numbers() which I have tested independently and it works - it provides a single positive integer). I'm not very experienced in javascript, but have developed the below from learning online. Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

```
function validate() {
var message = "This number is ";
var number;
var value = numbers();
var indicator = true;

for (int i=2; i <= value/2; i++) {
   number = value % i;
   if (number==0)  {
      indicator = false;
      //or indicator = number % 2 != 0;
    break;
   }
 }

 if (indicator) {
 message += "a prime number.";
 }
 else {
 message += "not a prime number.";
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = message;  
}
```

Comment: What's your question? If you're looking for a code review check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry! Meant to say it doesn't work! No error messages displayed. Will update now.

Comment: `int i=2;` isn’t going to work in JS. And I _do_ get the error message “SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer”.

Comment: @Xufox re int i = 2; Yes! I must have reverted back to java without realising! Is the for loop referencing statement 1 in the for loop? Also, how are you getting these error messages? Do I need to use a different IDE?

Comment: I believe, although I haven't fully tested, that it's working! Thank you!

Comment: Use your developer console in your browser to see the runtime error messages. I personally use SublimeText as my IDE, and there are syntax validation/"lint" plugins that allow it to do some in-editor error detection and highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Only even number that is prime is 2, so discard all the others that is divisible by 2
2. Minimize the iteration by considering odds only
3. Minimize a bit more by iterating to root of given number

So what you can do is write a method like the following:

```
function isPrime(number) {
    if (number === 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 === 0) return false;
    var flag = true;
    var i, length = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number));

    for (i = 3; i <= length; i += 2) {
        if (number % i === 0) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `int` to `var` in `for` loop

`for (var i=2; i <= value/2; i++) {`